# if statement в sql

Tags: mysql, if

Здравствуйте, есть две таблицы в СУБД MySQL:

1. user

   ```
   +----+-------+----------+
   | id | login | password |
   +----+-------+----------+
   |  1 | o1    | 123      |
   +----+-------+----------+
   ```
2. session

   ```
   +-------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
   | token | active | user_id | create_time         | update_time         |
   +-------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
   | first |      1 |       1 | 2017-07-06 12:31:00 | 2017-07-06 12:31:00 |
   +-------+--------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
   ```

Нужно сделать следующее: если в `user` есть строка где логин o1, то добавляем 
запись в `session`.

Делал примерно так, но не вышло:

```
if((select count(*) from user where login = 'o1')>0, 
    insert into session values ('first', 1, now(), now()), 
    select NULL from user);
```

Comment: *нужно сделать следующее: если в user есть строка где логин o1, то то добавляем запись в session...* А если нет?

Comment: то ничего... я думал это делается так select NULL from user, но видимо нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если user.login уникально, то

```
INSERT INTO session (token,active,user_id,create_time,update_time)
SELECT 'first', 1, user.id, now(), now()
FROM user
WHERE user.login = 'o1'
```

Если неуникально - ну добавить LIMIT 1 (а лучше - дополнительные условия отбора, чтобы выбралась ОДНА запись).

Только непонятно, зачем делать ручные присвоения полям create_time и update_time, когда есть автоматизированное DEFAULT и ON UPDATE...

Comment: хм, спасибо, правда не понял до конца как так...
user_id у session зависит от id user... если бы показали как сделать чтоб автоматом создавался user_id, то вообще б было супер

Comment: ааа, вы ж user.id использовали... да, тогда вопрос снять, спасибо

Comment: а не подскажете как без вложенных запросов сделать то же самое? как-нибудь через left join

Comment: В приведённом коде нет вложенных запросов.

Comment: а тогда с помощью цепочки элементарных запросов получить то же самое... я просто не смог пока

Answer (score 1):

Функция `IF` может быть выполнена только из запроса/встроенной процедуры.

> нужно сделать следующее: если в user есть строка где логин o1, то то добавляем запись в session... делал примерно так, но не вышло:

Вставки по условию можно добиться с помощью `INSERT-SELECT-WHERE`. Например так:

```
insert into session 
select 't2', 1, 1, now(), now()
from dual
where (select count(*) from user where login = 'o1') > 0;
```

Или так:

```
insert into session 
select 't3', 1, 1, now(), now()
from dual
where exists (select 1 from user where login = 'o1');
```

Количество столбцов в приведенном вами запросе и в таблице `sessions` не совпадает. Проверьте запрос еще раз, возможно потребуется выбор `user_id`.

Comment: а в нашем случае какую структуру имеет таблица dual?

Comment: @xperious `DUAL` в MySQL — это стандартный псевдоним, который используется для выборки данных без обращения к какой либо таблице. В данном случае ее можно считать таблицей из одной строки. Можете посмотреть в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), либо почитать в [википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table).